# JPA method to update roles for users

Tags: java, hibernate, authorization, jpa

In my Spring MVC app I have `User` and `Role` entities.

`User`:

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private Set<Role> roles;

    // other fields, getters and setters
}
```

`Role`:

```
public class Role {
    private Long id;

    // other fields, getters and setters
}
```

I have a service method with the following signature:

```
@Transactional
void setRolesByUserId(Map<Long, Set<Long>> rolesByUserId)
```

The key of the `Map` is a `User` ID and the corresponding value is a `Set` of `Role` IDs that needs to be assigned to the user.

My implementation:

```
public void setRolesByUserId(Map<Long, Set<Long>> rolesByUserId) {
    // 1.
    Map<Long, Role> roles = roleRepository.findAll()
        .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Role::getId, Function.identity()));

    // 2.
    userRepository.findAllById(rolesByUserId.keySet())
            // 3.
            .forEach(user -> user.setRoles(rolesByUserId.get(user.getId())
                    .stream().map(roles::get).collect(Collectors.toSet())));
}
```

So basically the flow is the following:

1. fetch all the `Role` entities from the DB into a `Map<Long, Role>` (where the key is the `Role` ID and the value is the `Role` entity itself)
2. fetch the `User` entities from the DB that needs to be modified
3. for each `User`, iterate through the `Role` IDs to be assigned, fetch the corresponding `Role` entities from the `Map`, collect them into a `Set` and assign it to the `User`

Can this method be optimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest optimization potential I see is readability. Note that forEach() does not have any advantage over a good-ole-for-loop from a technical perspective, but in many cases makes the code more complicated, especially when the lambda is not trivial.

Thus, I'd replace the steps 2 and 3 with the following equivalent code:

```
for(User user : userRepository.findAllById(rolesByUserId.keySet())) {
    Set<Roles> roles = rolesByUserId.get(user.getId()).stream()
        .map(roles::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    user.setRoles(roles);
}
```

- it is absolutely clear, that you iterate over user objects
- the roles are plainly visible
- no nested streaming or lambdas
- and you can set a breakpoint at various places to inspect the current user and role-set in a debugger

Answer (score 1):

Well, you created a good code so far. Your lamda is OK. But there are some things about naming which could be improved

1. About the API `setRolesByUserId`, it is OK to accept userId as long. But about role, it could be better to change the Set to Set, and i think you're about to update for `List of user`, hence the name should change to `updateUserWithRoleSet`.
2. IMHO, It is totally OK to update one user at once => `updateUserWithRole(long userId, Set<Role> roles>`